# How do I figure out which applications on my computer is using UPnP broadcasting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, media, xbox360, upnp

I'm trying to get the media server **TVersity** to work, but when the service is supposed to start, it gets stuck on "Starting" and NEVER moves on. I've read that TVersity won't work if I've got other programs on my computer using UPnP, and µTorrent was mentioned. I've switched off UPnP on µTorrent without success though.

Later I found out that Skype also uses UPnP, so I dug into the advanced settings and disabled it for Skype, but still TVersity wouldn't start.

Much later, I discovered by random that Hamachi also used UPnP, so after some searching through the settings i found and disabled it. But of course TVersity still won't start.

Of course after all this I'm thinking I could have tons of applications on my computer that hinders TVersity from starting, **so is there any tools out there that can track down the processes on my PC that uses UPnP?**

Also, any other advice on why TVersity might not be starting would be great. :)

*FYI: I **have** started a thread on their forums. In fact I started it weeks ago without any replies, despite my bump*

Comment: Edit your post to include your OS please. Did you try the TVersity Forums?

Comment: Did you try to start it in debug mode as suggested by TVersity trouble shooting FAQ?

Comment: @Moab: Yes I've started in debug mode. According to the trouble shooting FAQ my install does work in debug mode, and the problem is with the service